# Open local HTML file in default web browser

Tags: ruby

IS there any way in Ruby to open a local HTML file in the user's default web browser? I could do something like:

```
system("open /path/to/file.html")
```

But that would only work on Mac OS X. Are there any solutions that work on any platform?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [launchy](http://copiousfreetime.rubyforge.org/launchy/) gem.

First, install the gem:

```
$ [sudo] gem install launchy
```

Then, in your ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'launchy'

Launchy::Browser.run("/path/to/file.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do system specific calls.

system() is like writing the command on the local system command line (that's my understanding anywayz)

I can't do what you have done on Windows 7. I have to call explorer and it opens in my default browser.

Windows 7 Example: (opens in Chrome, my default browser)

```
system("explorer file:///C:/path_to_file")
```

**Note:** I needed to put file:/// at the start otherwise it opens in Explorer instead of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not desirable, however worst case, you can check the value of `RUBY_PLATFORM`. This returns the operating system platform.

Semi-Pseudo Code:

```
cmd = case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /darwin/
    "open /path/to/file.html"
  when /windows/ #fix this, I'm not sure.
    "explorer file:///C:/path_to_file"
  else
    "default"
end

system(cmd)
```